# Excel Data Validation Source for different columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am making a series of cascading dropdowns in Excel. When a user selects an option in ColumnB, the sheet finds a list "Name"d = ColumnB value and set the validation for that column with that list.

[image: Data Validation]

It is working fine

[image: Options Loaded]

But when I drag the cell in the whole column and try applying the Data Validation property to all cells, instead of selecting the previous cells respectively, it is defining every Data Validation property with the specific cell with which the first cell was binded.

[image: Data Validation source for another cell]

It is not much of a problem as I can do that for individual cell, but I will be setting the data and names through code later, so I need to find a way that every Data Validation source contains a reference to its previous cell instead of that one specific cell.

Comment: Try removing the "$" sign in "$B$2". Instead try "$B2" or "B2" 
does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the $ sign. $ sign means that the reference is absolute and the cell reference in the formulas won't change when the cell is dragged or copied.

Another solution is to define the data validation for the entire column and you don't have to drag anymore.